# (vue router) Is there a neat way to not duplicate code when creating two routes with an almost identical view?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a `NewArticleView` vue component that is mapped to **/articles/new**, like this:

```js
const routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: '/articles/new',
        name: 'New Article',
        component: NewArticleView
    },
    ...
]
```

The view is basically just a form.

I want to create an `EditArticleView` component but it feels wrong making a new component, since it will be almost identical to `NewArticleView`.

I really wish there was a way to send an `edit` flag or something when navigating to the route (something like `router.push('/articles/new', editArticle=true)`), which modifies the behaviour of the component. Like binding form values to the article I want to edit, instead of an empty form, and use an update api call instead of the one used for creating a new article.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make one component like `ArticleView` which accepts a prop named `editArticle` :

```
  {
        path: '/articles/new',
        name: 'ArticleView',
        component: NewArticleView,
         props: route => ({ editArticle: route.query.editArticle})
    },
```

then use it like `/articles/new?editArticle=true`

Comment: That's excactly what I was looking for! The use of a query is very clever. Do you think it's a good way to pass the article id of the article I want to edit as a query as well? And what do you think is the best way to bind the form data with the corresponding article data? Is there a way to avoid having to make an api call, maybe load it from a global state with vuex?

Comment: Side note, do you think that, semantically, it makes more sense to name the route **/articles/update** with a newArticle flag?

Comment: Name your component with a name that is not confusing like `ArticleForm` and pass the article id as param like `path: '/articles/:id'` then inside the component  you could get using `this.$route.params.id`

Comment: you could make an API call inside the mounted hook but it should be done using a service something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693060/nuxt-js-the-best-place-for-api-calls/63693322#63693322