# Registering Nuxt Plugins: Globally vs Manual Import

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, es6-modules, nuxtjs3

I had made two repositories as plugins where I places my API calls.

**plugins/repos/UserRepository.js** (I need that in /views/users.vue)

**plugins/repos/PostRepository.js** (I need that in /views/posts.vue)

To utilize these plugins I have two options:

1. Register these plugins globally by listing them in the plugins array in nuxt.config.js
2. Manually import each repo in the respective vue component.

In the case of the first option, my repo looks like this:

```
export default (ctx, inject) => {

const data={
        getAll(){
            return context.$axios
            .$get("/users");
        }
    }

    inject('userRepo', data);
}
```

The main advantage of the first approach is I can access the context. But If I manually import it in my component (second approach) then I need to manually pass the context in the plugin.

But the main disadvantage of the first approach is it makes the plugin universally available. **So my main question is: is the first one is a bad approach in terms of memory consumption as I don't need PostRepository in users.vue but it still be auto imported by Nuxt because I mentioned it in the plugins array in nuxt.config.js?**

**Please tell me what's the best way to handle this as I had dozens of repositories so registering all of them globally is a good idea?**

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much answered yourself to your question. Memory-wise and also in terms of loading times of your SPA, it will always be better to make a local import rather than having a lot globally even if you only use it 5% of the time.

Then, you can always access the context by itself as usual without needing the plugin aka `this.$axios`. What would be the blocking use-case here?

If you're working with Nuxt3, you could also use composables.

Comment: There is no blockage, my only concern is I can't access context (this.$axios) in the Repository if I manually import it. In that case, I need to explicitly pass the context from where I'm using the repo.

Comment: @habib depends on where you do actually import it, if it's in a `.vue` file you should be gucci if you're using the [`axios` nuxt module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module). If it's in a regular `.js` file, I guess you could use a regular axios.

Comment: I'm importing it in vue file. Btw, what do you mean by  gucci here?

Comment: @habib I'm not sure why you don't have access to `this.$axios` in your components but if you look at the [usage page](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage), you are totally able to use it there. Did you installed the module properly? If you did, you will have access to it.

Comment: My apologies, I'm trying to access this.$axios in a js file /plugins/repos/UserRepository.js

Comment: @habib if it's not in a `.vue` file nor in a vuex one, just a regular API model JS file, you then should use the [regular axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) into your JS files. Indeed, `this.$axios` is to be used withing Vue/Nuxt context. If you get out of it, no point into using the nuxt module.